# Workflow "Failed on start" whenever call by PowerShell

Tags: 2010, powershell, designer-workflow, error, web-config

We are using SP2010. I have prepared a PowerShell script to trigger particular workflow on particular object. Here is the script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://url/";
$list = $web.Lists["My list"];
$manager=$web.Site.WorkFlowManager
$association = $list.WorkFlowAssociations |Where { $_.Name -eq "Name of Workflow"}
$data = $association.AssociationData
$data=$association.AssociationData
$item = $list.GetItemById(1234)
$wf=$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data,$true)
```

We have a dev and test sharepoint environment. Our dev environment is a single server installation. The script above can start the workflow but immediately turn to "Failed on start" error (and stopped). By running same script on our test environment, it works perfect.

I checked the ULS log, it indicate my web.config have problem.

> RunWorkflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: An error occurred
>   creating the configuration section handler for
>   System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler/authorizedTypes: Could
>   not find file 'C:\Users\devserver1\AppData\Local\Temp\ottgdnfv.dll'.
>   (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config line 683)

I have compared the web.config file between two environment and they are the same.

The same workflow can be triggered manually (on both environment) without problem.

Comment: are you by any chance running this command with System Account ? It wont work with that.

Comment: I have tried change the script to impersonate a site collection admin and then a normal user. The workflow initiator changed to new person but still same error.

Comment: Oh I love it how after hours of googling I always find that one single SO post that exactyl matches my problem ... with NO ANSWER.

Comment: And here it comes: My account was assigned a global permission policy with a checkmark at "operates as system". After deleting the policy my account did no longer "operate as system" and it worked. Thanks to Eric Fang: http://fangdahai.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-start-workflow-in-powershell.html

Comment: @ben Although it is 3 years ago and I am no longer work in that environment, I believe it is the solution.

Comment: :-) well, than I will post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the PowerShell session on the SharePoint server, make sure to launch the PowerShell app as admin.